# Problema para juntar dois SELECTs em uma instrução só

Tags: mysql

Preciso de ajuda em uma instrução SQL referente ao banco de dados MySQL.

O `select` abaixo me retorna dados vindo de duas tabelas. Uso para um sistema de buscas que estou desenvolvendo.

```
SELECT perfil_usuario_unificado.nome_fantasia
      ,perfil_usuario_unificado.descricao_emp
      ,perfil_usuario_unificado.cnpj
      ,identificacao_acesso.id
  FROM perfil_usuario_unificado
 INNER JOIN identificacao_acesso
    ON perfil_usuario_unificado.id_ia = identificacao_acesso.id
 INNER JOIN b_tag_pesquisa
    ON perfil_usuario_unificado.id_ia = b_tag_pesquisa.id_ia
 WHERE b_tag_pesquisa.tag_pesquisa LIKE ('%WEB%')
 ORDER BY perfil_usuario_unificado.nome_fantasia ASC;
```

Já o `select` abaixo faz uma contagem em um determinado campo da tabela. Uso para contar quantos "curtir" tem um determinado registro.

```
SELECT COUNT(gostei_nao_gostei) AS quantidade
  FROM interacao_social
 WHERE para_id_ia = '2'
   AND gostei_nao_gostei = '0';
```

> **Problema:**
>   Preciso juntar os dois `select` em uma mesma instrução, mas não sei como fazer.

Seguem os esquemas das tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE `identificacao_acesso` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `niv` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `usuario` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `senha` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

CREATE TABLE `interacao_social` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `de_id_ia` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `para_id_ia` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `gostei_nao_gostei` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `check_in` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=10
;

CREATE TABLE `b_tag_pesquisa` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_ia` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tag_pesquisa` VARCHAR(500) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COMMENT='tabela de tag de pesquisa'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;

CREATE TABLE `perfil_usuario_unificado` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_ia` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cnpj` VARCHAR(14) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `razao_social` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nome_fantasia` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `descricao_emp` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cpf` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nome_pf` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cep` INT(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `endereco` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `complemento_end` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `numero_end` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `bairro` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cidade` VARCHAR(25) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `estado` CHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5
;
```

Comment: Diego, Eu até dei umas pesquisadas e tal e não achei nada, acredito que não dá para juntar dois selects da forma que você quer não. Aproveitando deixo aqui a minha opinião: Eu recomendo você dividir isso em duas consultas porque já está super grande a sua query e quanto maior mais processamentos ele gastará.

Comment: Não é possível unir estes dois selects, para usar o UNION (união de selects) os campos retornados devem ser os mesmos nos dois selects

Comment: @AlexandrePreviatti nao necessariamente. vc pode resolver com alias e valores de padding, e usar sintaxe posicional em vez dos nomes.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem duas formas para fazer isso. uma é usando o `JOIN` e outra seria um `select` com `SubQuery`.

Respostas:

> SubQuery

```
    SELECT perfil_usuario_unificado.nome_fantasia, perfil_usuario_unificado.descricao_emp,
        perfil_usuario_unificado.cnpj, identificacao_acesso.id,
(select 
COUNT(gostei_nao_gostei) FROM interacao_social
WHERE para_id_ia = '2' AND gostei_nao_gostei = '0'
and  --- aqui tem que haver uma ligação entre as tabelas) AS quantidade

     FROM perfil_usuario_unificado 
     INNER JOIN identificacao_acesso
        ON perfil_usuario_unificado.id_ia = identificacao_acesso.id 
     INNER JOIN b_tag_pesquisa ON perfil_usuario_unificado.id_ia = b_tag_pesquisa.id_ia 
     WHERE b_tag_pesquisa.tag_pesquisa LIKE ('%WEB%') 
     ORDER BY perfil_usuario_unificado.nome_fantasia ASC;
```

O `JOIN` nesse caso seria um pouco mais complicado porque você teria que agrupa seus dados.

Passa mais detalhes dos campos chaves das suas tabelas caso precise de uma reposta melhor.

Comment: Olá, tambem acho que a melhor solução passa por subquery só falta mesmo saber a ligação da tabela interacao_social para as outras tabelas.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT perfil_usuario_unificado.nome_fantasia, perfil_usuario_unificado.descricao_emp,
    perfil_usuario_unificado.cnpj, identificacao_acesso.id,
    COUNT(gostei_nao_gostei) AS quantidade -- segundo select
  FROM perfil_usuario_unificado,
     interacao_social -- segundo select
  INNER JOIN identificacao_acesso
    ON perfil_usuario_unificado.id_ia = identificacao_acesso.id 
  INNER JOIN b_tag_pesquisa ON perfil_usuario_unificado.id_ia = b_tag_pesquisa.id_ia 
  WHERE b_tag_pesquisa.tag_pesquisa LIKE ('%WEB%') 
    AND para_id_ia = '2' AND gostei_nao_gostei = '0'; -- segundo select
 ORDER BY perfil_usuario_unificado.nome_fantasia ASC;
```

Comment: Para uma melhor formatação, use [markdown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) na hora de formatar o código, ou simplesmente clique em `{}` com o código selecionado.